# Is it possible to revive a NiMH cell with low capacity

Tags: nimh

I have a bunch of 2100 mAh NiMH cells that have been lying around for many years (probably about 8 years). They still had 1.2-1.3 V when I recently took them out of the drawer, but when I tried to do a charge/discharge cycle they only had about 1/20 - 1/10 the rated capacity.

When I search on Google all I can find is advice about trying to apply a high voltage to the cells for a little while. But as far as I understand the "high voltage" shock treatment is to attempt to revive NiMH cells/batteries with low voltage, so smart-chargers will accept them and start charging, and that is not my problem.

My problem is that the cells currently do not hold much of a charge.

I have tried to discharge -> charge 5 times (with 15 minute pauses in between), and while the capacity increases, it's from around 1/20 to about 1/10. Should I just try some more cycles or is it a waste of my time and effort?

Is there another known way to revive such batteries?

Comment: Afraid not.  Batteries are like a sponge; charge by soaking up water.  Usage draws the water out.  Rinse-and-repeat enough times, and the sponge deteriorates.  A worn-out battery is just that - a worn out atomic sponge.  Any "trick" to make it seem like capacity has been restored is just a trick - capacity cannot be restored.  Recycling them properly is the best course of action (many battery stores will take them, call and ask.)  On the plus-side, upgrading to modern battery types will yield an impressive performance improvement.

Comment: It's dead Jim. Time to get new cells.

Comment: The NiMh articles on "batteryuniversity" are pretty decent. I recommend reading those. You already did few cycles on the cells, which is one of the methods. Another method for reviving cells is discharging them to ~0.4V per cell (and maybe waiting few hours), which should remove "memory" effect, I think. Don't expect miracles, though. Edit: By the way, new cells aren't too expensive, and you can get the low-self-discharge ones (10% per year?), which are pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. I should probably have written that they have not been extensively used before being put in the drawer. They have definitely been used for less than 30 cycles. So I wouldn't call them worn out. And they're Panasonic branded, so not some cheap crap. They have however been lying around for long, which is obviously also not ideal. Recycling is not a problem around here, but if they could be revived I'd prefer not to throw something good away. Half the reason I haven't used them is that I've switched to Eneloop/Ikea. AFAIK memory effect is for NiCd, not NiMH.